# Mathematica Pick stop a list as soon as I get a 3

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

Here's what I have...

```
Select[roll, # <= 3 &]
```

Now, the list that follows may have one 3 or two three's. I want it to stop at the first three from left to right.

Mathematician trying to code.

Comment: Can you clarify?  What should `f[{1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}]` give?  `{1,2,5,2}`, `{1,2,2}`, `{1,2,5,2,3}` or `{1,2,2,3}`?

Comment: It gives a List of random numbers. I want show a list up to the first 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note**: I removed my original posting, which was basically like that of belisarius.  Here's another try...

If you are sure that the number 3 is a member of `roll` then this should work:

```
TakeWhile[roll, # != 3 &]~Append~3
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Take[roll, LengthWhile[roll, # != 3 &] +1]
```

If you cannot make this assumption, just test first with `MemberQ`

**EDIT**: Credit goes to TomD for suggesting the +1 in the second solution, which eliminates the need to use `Append`.

Comment: I learned a lot from this answer.  A very slight variant of method two? `Take[roll, LengthWhile[roll, # != 3 &] + 1]`

Comment: @TomD Your variant nicely eliminates the need for `Append`. I really like it.

Answer (score 6):

This is an order of magnitude faster than `TakeWhile` on a list of integers.

```
list /. {x___, 3, ___} :> {x}
```

To get the list *through* 3, just use `{x, 3}` on the right hand side.

Comment: Your solution seems to work. (although I think it was meant to include the 3 after the x).  But in any case, why does Mma not allow a three to be part of the x sequence? I.e. How does it know that you want the FIRST three?

Comment: @David It simply gives the first match, and the default method is shortest first, on the first pattern.  You can get all matches with `ReplaceList[{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5}, {x___, 3, ___} :> {x}]` or the longest with `{1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5} /. {Longest[x___], 3, ___} :> {x}`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
f[list_, item_] := list[[1 ;; Position[list, item][[1, 1]]]]
```

Usage:

```
f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2}, 3]
(*
->{1,2,3}
*)
f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2}, 5]
(*
->{1,2,3,4,1,4,3,4,3,5}
*)
```

If you also want to filter values greater than 3, you may just use your code wrapping mine:

```
g[list_, item_] :=  Select[list[[1 ;; Position[list, item][[1, 1]]]], # <= 3 &]
```

so:

```
g[{-1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2}, 3]
(*
->{-1,1,2,1,3}
*)
```

Comment: I posted my solution below when yours was still showing  as: `f[list_, toSearch_, times_] := 
 If[Length@# < times, list, list[[1 ;; #[[times, 1]]]]] &@
  Position[list, toSearch]`

Comment: @David No problem, I misunderstood the question at first sight.